# Order by Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table in my database that has a field called round with the following records

- Regular Season -1
- Regular Season -2
- Regular Season -10
- Regular Season -11
- Regular Season -21

etc

but when ordering with `orderBy ('round')` I returned them like that

- Regular Season -1
- Regular Season -10
- Regular Season -11
- Regular Season -2
- Regular Season -21

and I need it consecutively

Comment: Is that field a text field or a numeric field? Can you show the query you use?

Comment: yes sounds like a `varchar` instead of `integer`

Comment: Its a varchar field, I use Fixture::select('round')->gruopBy('round')->orderBy('round', 'asc')->get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column is text-based and therefore is sorted *alphabetically*, not *numerically*.  Split your database column into two:

```php
$table->string('round');           // e.g. "Semifinals", "Regular Season"
$table->integer('round_number');   // e.g. 1, 2, 3, ... , 10
```

Then you can do `->orderBy('round', 'asc')->orderBy('round_number', 'asc');`

Answer (score 0):

You can store `round` as a [signed integer column](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-columns) instead of string in your DB:

```php
$table->integer('round');
$table->string('type');
```

Now you can use `orderBy('round')` to get desired result.

You may also [define an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your model for `round` like this:

```php
/**
 * Get the formatted round value.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRoundAttribute($value)
{
    return "{$this->type} {$value}";
}
```

Comment: No a can't do that, because sometimes the record can be Semifinals 1

Comment: @BarbaroJavier still possible to split your column into 2, string and integer.